# How to redirect to the home page after google registration?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have react firebase v9 google authentication.

Login:

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
const Login = () => {
const navigate = useNavigate();

 const signInWithGoogle = async () => {

    signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
      .then((result) => {
        const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
        const token = credential.accessToken;
        const user = result.user;
        navigate('/'); // Redirect not work
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        const email = error.customData.email;
        const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
      });
  };

 ....

  <Button variant="dark" onClick={signInWithGoogle}>
    Google
  </Button>
...
```

How to redirect to the home page after google registration?

Update:
problem in

```
    const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
    const token = credential.accessToken;
    const user = result.user;
```